# SQL error while creating table , VARCHAR2 not a valid expecting INT, BIGINT

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEEs
(
ENAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,   -- getting error here as VARCHAR2 not a valid expecting INT, BIGINT...
ESRNO VARCHAR2(7) PRIMARY KEY CHECK(LENGTH(ESRNO)=6),
BDATE DATE,
ADDRESS VARCHAR2(20),
SEX CHAR(3) DEFAULT('M'),
SALARY NUMBER(7) CHECK(SALARY BETWEEN 20000 AND 40000),
MGRSRNO VARCHAR2(6),
DNO NUMBER(3)
);
```

Find the error at line 2, DB used Workbench.

What is the correct answer and why?

Comment: If you use MySQL, then don't use Oracle-specific data types. Read about data types supported by MySQL here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html Please understand that every implementation of SQL has different features. You can't use an SQL script designed for Oracle on any other brand of SQL product, and vice-versa.